# List all the collections of database using mongocxx

Tags: collections, mongo-cxx-driver

I have been trying to pull list of all the collections present in database and trying to use :

```cpp
cursor list_collections(bsoncxx::document::view filter = {});
```

but not able to iterate over the collections.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};
   // auto collection = conn["test"]["restaurants"];
    mongocxx::database db = conn["test"];
    auto cursor1 = db.list_collections();
    for (const bsoncxx::document::view& doc :cursor1)
    {
        bsoncxx::document::element ele = doc["name"];
        std::string name = ele.get_utf8().value.to_string();
        std::cout <<name<< std::endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `db.list_collection_names()` which returns an `std::vector<std::string>`, so: `for (const auto& name : db.list_collection_names()) std::cout << name << '\n';`